# react setting without webpack

Tags: reactjs, webpack

I'm trying to set up react project without CRA

Before, I've succeed reactApp with CDN.
So this time, I just want to set up reactApp with npm.

I installed react, react-dom by npm.
and index.html below

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <title>Document</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="root"></div>

    <script type="module" src="./src/index.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

index.js below

```js
import React from "/react";
import { ReactDOM } from "react-dom";

const createEle = React.createElement;

const domContainer = document.querySelector("#root");
const root = ReactDOM.createRoot(domContainer);

root.render(createEle(LikeButton));

function LikeButton() {
  const [liked, setLike] = React.useState(false); //

  if (liked) {
    domContainer.style.backgroundColor = "red";
    return createEle("button", { onClick: () => setLike(false) }, "Hate");
  } else {
    domContainer.style.backgroundColor = "green";

    return createEle("button", { onClick: () => setLike(true) }, "Like");
  }
}
```

I don't want to use webpack, babel.

but after I open the index.html, it doesn't work. Only after setting webpack, it works.

So how webpack makes reactApp alive?

Many people  say  that  to Set up  reactApp without CRA ,  it needs webpack because  it  bundles  complicated so many files .

But In my case , I simplify the App  and  I just want to run it.

I want to know  the webpack's role in my case.  (the purpose i need webpack  in this case

Answer (score 0):

Webpack inject `react` and `reactdom` source

To use it without webpack or other module bundler you need to add react source

React cdn for development

```html
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react@18/umd/react.development.js"></script>
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@18/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script>
```

React cdn for production

```html
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react@18/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@18/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
```

```js
// Import is commented because script is not used as module in stack snippet. you can uncomment this.
//import React from "/react";
//import {
//  ReactDOM
//} from "react-dom";

const createEle = React.createElement;

const domContainer = document.querySelector("#root");
const root = ReactDOM.createRoot(domContainer);

root.render(createEle(LikeButton));

function LikeButton() {
  const [liked, setLike] = React.useState(false); //

  if (liked) {
    domContainer.style.backgroundColor = "red";
    return createEle("button", {
      onClick: () => setLike(false)
    }, "Hate");
  } else {
    domContainer.style.backgroundColor = "green";

    return createEle("button", {
      onClick: () => setLike(true)
    }, "Like");
  }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8" />
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
  <title>Document</title>
</head>

<body>
  <div id="root"></div>

  <script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react@18/umd/react.development.js"></script>
  <script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@18/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script>

  <script type="module" src="./src/index.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Thanks to reply! Actually, I've already succeed with CDN. So I just wanted to run only NPM without webpack. As you say above,  "webpack injects react, reactdom source", then just only setiting up `npm i react react-dom`  cannot import these source without webpack? Do I understand right?

Comment: So you want to use npm installed `react` and `react-dom` without cdn and webpack?

Comment: Yes, and I just want to know how it works. when I use just CDN script, I can see the react, reactDOM object on console. and I just use it by import.

"Webpack implements react, react-dom package in node_modules in previous so that my code can run"

Am I right? I'm confused..

Comment: If you use `create-react-app` it hide webpack babel configuration. The downside of not using are you cannot use `jsx`, new feature polyfill, and etc.

Comment: And you cannot use hot module reload or hmr for short. hmr is your application refresh automatically without losing state when you changes your code in development.